# GAE Resteasy "WARNING: No file found for ..path.."

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jetty, resteasy

I am developing a RESTful api that I would like to run in the Google App Engine. I am planning on using Resteasy, Spring, Jackson and GAE.

I have a working project running on a Tomcat 7 server, but when I add the same sources & configuration in a GAE project, I get the following jetty log message, and 404 as response.

**WARNING: No file found for: /locationapi/api-v1/test**

That happens when I try to access: http://localhost:8888/locationapi/api-v1/test

I have attached:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

<!--     <context-param> -->
<!--         <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name> -->
<!--         <param-value>ro.test.locationapi.TestResource</param-value> -->
<!--     </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api-v1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api-v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the test resource:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/")
public class TestResource {

    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    public Response test() {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

}
```

Note:
     1. code works fine on a Tomcat 7 server.
     2. Resteasy version 2.2.3.GA
     3. Spring-* version 3.2.0.RELEASE

Can anyone figure out why I get that warning and 404 as response?
I think that Jetty thinks I am requesting files..

Thanks in advance,
Catalin

Comment: The 404 occurs when something, anything, else doesn't handle the request. This includes all of spring, plus all of resteasy, plus jetty's own default servlet.  Nothing can answer the request, so its a 404.

Comment: I can't agree with you @Joakim more. But what startles me is that everything is ok on Tomcat, and 404 occurs on GAE. Still investigating ...